# Is there any way to get show the data coming from api?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am building a spa in which I need to get the data from the controller I am getting the data from API but I am not able to display the data in my vue controller.

```
   export default {
 data() {
    return {
      ids:{},
        form: new Form({
          name:'',
          relation:'',
          gender:'',
          dob:'',
          marriage_status:'',
          matrimonial:'',
          email:'',
          mobile:'',
          father_name:'',
          mother_name:'',
          address:'',
          city:'',
          state:'',
          occupation:'',
          department:'',
          post_graduate_degree:'',
          post_graduate_university:'',
          post_graduate_university_city:'',
          post_graduate_university_state:'',
          post_graduate_university_percentage:'',
          post_graduate_year_of_passing:'',
          graduate_degree:'',
          graduate_university:'',
          graduate_university_city:'',
          graduate_university_state:'',
          graduate_university_percentage:'',
          graduate_year_of_passing:'',
          class_12_board : '',
          class_12_school_name:'',
          class_12_percentage:'',
          class_12_year_of_passing:'',
          class_12_city:'',
          class_10_board:'',
          class_10_school_name:'',
          class_10_percentage:'',
          class_10_year_of_passing:'',
          class_10_city:'',
          username:'',
          password:''

          })
        }
      },
    methods:{
  loaduser(){

   axios.get('api/userDetails').then(function (response) {
// handle success
 this.ids = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
  console.log(this.ids);
  })
   },
      created() {
      this.loaduser();
   }
    }
```

I am getting data from api but I am not able to save that data in ids object. How to achieve that.

I have already tried 
this.ids = response.data
but it is not working.

I want to get the user details like username, name, email etc in the ids object. or if there is any other good way to do this.
this is my controller file

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\UserDetail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Auth;

class UserDetailsController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
 $this->middleware('auth:api');

}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
  return auth('api')->user();
//return $user = Auth::user();
 }
```

Comment: Your code says `ids = response.data`, which is assigning it to a local variable -- an undeclared one, so your code likely won't even compile.  Please post the code you are actually using.

Comment: please go through the code I have added code: " I am getting following response.
    created_at: "2019-10-24 14:52:03"
    email: "*****xysesh1989@gmail.com"
email_verified_at: null
gotra: "kashyap"
id: 1
name: "Durgesh Tanwar"
updated_at: "2019-10-24 14:52:03"
username: "durgesh"
usertype: "family"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you missed is "this" . You are assigning the data to local variable. Here I have updated the code

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ids:{},
      //
    },
  methods:{
    loaduser(){
      axios.get('api/userDetails').then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        this.ids = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(this.ids);
      })
    },
    //
  }
}
```